# Anyone have any resources on understanding .pbxproj files?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to wrap my head around why the .pbxproj file changes as soon as I open Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> project.pbxproj is an important file in the Xcode configuration bundle. It is responsible for maintaining references to all of the linked files and their groupings, linked frameworks, and most importantly, the project’s build settings.

You should track the pbxproj file changes in your version control, if you found something wierd changes that happen when you open the project everytime, you'd better show the changes, eg. `git diff <path-to-pbxproj>`.

References: [Xcode and git: bridging the gap](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/xcode-and-git-bridging-the-gap)